# How to update multiple rows using more than one CASE statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, case

How can I use more than one CASE to update my rows in my table? I've been trying to write the script in different ways, but I'm sure the syntax is wrong. Any idea where the error is?

```
UPDATE NameToSplit
SET Aliases = CASE LEN(Alias)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 4 THEN Alias
    ELSE STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 5, 0, '-')END;
              CASE LEN(Alias)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 5 THEN Alias
    ELSE STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 6, 0, '-')END;
              CASE LEN(Alias)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 6 THEN Alias
    ELSE STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 7, 0, '-')END;
              CASE LEN(Alias)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 7 THEN Alias
    ELSE STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 8, 0, '-')END;
             CASE LEN(Alias)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 8 THEN Alias
    ELSE STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 9, 0, '-')END;
             CASE LEN(Alias)
    WHEN CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 9 THEN Alias
    ELSE STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 10, 0, '-')END;
```

The results must be like:

```
        Names                              Alias                  Aliases       
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    idealink.core.usergroup            core.usergroup         core.user-group
    idealink.core.userloginhistory     core.userloginhistory  core.user-loginhistory
   idealink.core.challengecategories   core.challengecategories core.challenge-categories
   idealink.core.activitydetails       core.activitydetails    core.activity-details
```

The length of the words after (core.) are different that's why I needed to create different cases to get all of them.

Comment: What you want to update add some sample data & desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you will be able to produce the result you want with a case.
Since the length off the world is not enough how will you know when to split with just the length better to use a string comparaison.

```
 UPDATE NameToSplit
    SET Aliases = CASE 
                     WHEN  ALIAS LIKE 'core.user%'
                        THEN STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 5, 0, '-') 
                    WHEN ALIAS LIKE 'core.challenge%'
                        THEN STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 10, 0, '-') 
                WHEN  ALIAS LIKE 'core.idea%'
                        THEN STUFF(Alias, CHARINDEX('.', Alias) + 5, 0, '-')    
                 -- .....
                 WHEN ALIAS LIKE 'core.%' 
                 THEN ALIAS --keep it at the end
                 END
```

If the Alias is only "core.user" then the ELSE will do is work and Aliases = alias

Comment: I don't think I can do this, because I have lots of tables to rename, I think it's not ideal to hardcode it,that's why I create more than one CASE to "try" to rename all of them at the same time.PS: I'm a newbie, so I don't understand sql very well   :(

Comment: Well if you don't have many different alias it will be very fast to update.I don't understand when you said rename all of them at the same time, with the update row by row all your aliases will be rename

Comment: I have a lot of aliases to update, here I just put some of them to show you I need different cases because the length of the words are different, some with 4 like(idea,user),challenge (9), award(5), and so on...

Comment: I see then you should use your CASE on the LEN after the .core and not the total LEN of Alias. I will edit my post

Comment: MAYBE I can do what you suggest, the only problem now is when the Alias is like( core.user) or (core.challenge) the result I get for the Aliases is NULL..... how to solve this? And THANK YOU in advance!!   :)

Comment: IF it's only core.user then you don't need to add a "-" to your alias and aliases = alias.

Comment: yeah I know, but when I run the code, it appears NULL in my Aliases column...and the Aliases column is like the final result I need, also I am writing to insert the (core.idea%) with core.user% because they have the same length, but it doesn't work...   :( :(

Comment: The last CASE should solve your problem but for the core.idea% it should work the same make sure to respect the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), you have your `ELSE` in the wrong spot. The syntax would be like this:

```
CASE ProductLine  
  WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'  
  WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'  
  WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'  
  WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'  
  ELSE 'Not for sale'  
END,
```

It ends up acting more like a `switch` statement where the subsequent `when` statements will only make an assertion if the previous statements have asserted false.

Comment: I'm confused now. Because I "think" I need the ELSE for each CASE statement to add the (-) to separate the words when the string is too long...

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, your problem is not the CASE statement. The main problem you have here is how to split a string that contains two or more words into only two strings.

For example, you need to find a way to split strings like these:

```
usergroup           user group (2 words split into two strings)
userloginhistory    user loginhistory (3 words split into two strings)
challengecategories challenge categories (2 words split into two strings)
activitydetails     activity details (2 words split into two strings)
```

So, somehow you need to find a common criteria. For example, at least, you need a list of all the possible starting words in your tables. In the example above these starting words are: *user*, *challenge* and *activity*. In that way, you can write some code to insert the dash right after one of those.

In order to you give a code solution, please let me know if getting this list of words is possible for you (I would probably put them in a temp table and use them from there).

Comment: Gonzales...I understand what you are saying..but what if I have many of them??I have loys of different possibilities...

Comment: The challenge here is how to split a string that can have several words in it. As far as I understand, you take the first word and then put a dash an then add the rest of the string, regardless the number of word it has. So, you need like a "dictionary" table where you can go and find each word in this "dictionary" to see if that word is the starting word in your string. Once found then is pretty easy to split.

Comment: You can read more about splitting a spaceless string into several words here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704003/How-to-add-spaces-between-words-in-a-spaceless-str

Comment: you're very welcome. I wish you the best of luck with this!